# How to add new Checkout step with custom form and save data in Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, checkout, onestepcheckout, customize

I am trying to add a new step in checkout and i have only virtual products which does not provide me shipping step so basically i  only get payment method only.
I want to  add a custom step having fields like text boxes check boxes and drop downs.

[image]

As you can see all this fields i want to add in my custom step and data should be saved.
What i tried is :

**1.** Made Shipping Form Visible for virtual product and tried to change mandatory fields but that didn't worked for me.
And other many things i have tried to alter shipping form but i decided to do this thing by making a new step and new form with the values getting saved.
I straggling on this from last 2 weeks but didn't able to solve this.
Again i am repeating i just want a new step with the form and values getting saved.
Form should have values given in the image.
Small Help Will Be Greatly Appreciated.

Thanks in Advanced :)

Comment: Did you try https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html ?

Comment: Yes it gave me new step but i dont know how to  add form and how to save custom data into DB

Comment: Can u plz help me for achiving my goal .
want to make form like above in new step and want to save data.
if u have any custom extension that can solve my problem or u can help me by posting code plz

Comment: That is easy. Create a API, post your form to that API by AJAX, after successful save response, pass step to review/payment

Comment: I dont have much knowledge in this plz refer me any good link so tht i can save and display my form in new step